# Does MSDaRT restore domain information?

Tags: windows-xp, configuration, active-directory

It's a Windows XP Box.

If I run the system restore through [MSDaRT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/mdop/dart.aspx), will the domain information will be restored?

Say, if user left the domain, after the restore, user will be part of the domain again?

Answer (score 0):

DaRT really doesn't interact with Active Directory, nor does AD run on an XP Box.

To begin with, you can't delete something from AD, you can only mark it as tombstoned and AD will later delete it. The time difference is configurable with a reasonable minimum for replication. You can [resurrect tombstoned objects in AD](http://www.petri.co.il/recovering-deleted-items-active-directory.htm) before they're deleted.

Comment: What I mean is, if the user on the XP machine left the windows domain, after the system restore on the XP machine, will the user be part of the domain again, or the user can only be reassigned by an administrator on that machine?

Comment: A user account local to the XP machine can not be part of a domain in the first place, so that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain administrator deleted (or disabled) the machine account and the user account, these actions will not be undone by a client's restore.

While the restored OS will look as if it has been configured for a domain membership, a logon attempt at the domain controller will fail as the credentials for the domain are not longer valid.